# Android : How to make an Dulax moon application?

Tags: android

http://www.apktop.com/deluxe-moon-1-44.html

i would love to develop and applicatoin as such but can anyone please tell me how to build something like this? or something to start up with?

thank you for the support

Answer (score 1):

Loshan, if you want to start developing applications for android, I suggest you read the [Android Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) to get yourself started. You'll also want to install the [Android Software Development Kit](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: i am currently developing android i ment small applications using sqlite... but i want to develop something as DULUXE MOON...

Comment: What duluxe moon are you trying to replicate. Can you please be more specific with your question?

Comment: in the deluxe moon application there is a facility you can rotate the moon by touching n turning.